Is there a problem with dynamic slice len in Go with this pattern?
So I have a situation where I know the max capacity of a slice so I create it with
slice := make([]int, 0, knownAbsoluteMaxCapacity)

However my fill pattern isn't sequential so sometimes I may insert index 5 instead of index 0 first. So I've come up with the following solution
slice = slice[:max(insertKey+1, len(slice))]
slice[insertKey] = insertValue

My question is does this have performance implications I'm not considering, or is there a better way to accomplish this pattern?
The reason I'm doing this is because I'd like to know the current len, basically the largest index that I have inserted. Because although I know the absolute maximum capacity I could possibly hit, I do want to know the actual capacity used as in most cases I never come close to the absolute maximum.

Slicing works on the capacity of the slice, and it is a constant time operation. So what you do is correct. However, there is a easier-to-read version of it:
// Pre-allocate the slice
slice := make([]int, knownMaxCapacity)
// Work with slice, keeping max index
{
  slice[insertKey]=insertValue
  if insertKey>max {
    max=insertKey
  }
}

//Truncate
slice=slice[:max+1]


This would avoid me needing to resize the slice all the time, the one issue I have is that the slice is stored in a struct and the methods updating it are a little all over the place, I did consider wrapping it in a new type with convenience methods to achieve something like this.

Depends on your use case. This is small enough to leave inline.
